# diff' ing files without modifying the original files ignoring whitespaces and newlines

Tags: bash, shell, sed, diff

I needed a bash script that involves writing a `diff` file, where I should see the changes in two files without modifying them ignoring spaces, tabs, and newlines as a part of the evaluation of one of the projects. For example,

**File 1:**

```
 00000001001010000101000000100000    #(add $t2,$t1,$t0(0x01285020))
 00000001100011010111000000100001    #(addu $t6, $t4, $t5(0x018d7021))  
 00000001001010000101000000100010    #(sub $t2,$t1,$t0(0x01285022))
```

**File2**

```
 00000001001010000101000000100000    #(add $t2, $t1, $t0(0x01285020))
 00000001100011010111000000100001    #(addu $t6, $t4, $t5(0x018d7021))
 00000001001010000101000000100010    #(sub $t2, $t1, $t0(0x01285022))
```

Both files are the same and `diff` shouldn't show any difference. I was trying something like,

`$ diff <(file1 sed 's/\s+//g') <(file2 sed 's/\s+//g') >>log.txt`
But it wasn't working. Any help with reasoning would be appreciated. I was trying other commands with diff too i.e, `-w,-B,-b` but none of them worked.
Any ideas on, `All words in the line after '#' should be ignored`, This works fine too for the one I am working upon.

Comment: Why your doing spaces even is not working in `sed` since you need to use `-E` flag of `sed` then it should fly then.

Comment: At the beginning you say that whitespaces and newlines are to be ignored, and at your epilogue you ask for ideas about ignoring all words after `#`. What is the question?

Comment: @thanasisp I asked for the general approach for what I have mentioned first. At my epilogue, I was thinking that the script after a **#** would work fine for the requirement. I actually wanted to both of them.

Comment: `diff -w` works fine for the requirement to ignore all whitespaces.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 why to remove spaces with sed, when `diff -w` is doing this? (if this is the question) Additionally this is a well-documented duplicate around SO posts.

Comment: @thanasisp, Hi, its written in answer its a fix of OP's attempt(added `diff -w` too now), but that dup wouldn't answer OP's 2nd query thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st query's answer:*** To substitute spaces into a single space to make lines similar looking for `diff`. Try adding `-E` flag to enable extended regular expression in `sed` which will recognize `/s+` so following will work for you(fixing OP's attempt here). To ignore spaces please use `diff -w file1 file2` command in an ideal way.

```
diff <(sed -E 's/\s+//g' file1) <(sed -E 's/\s+//g' file2)
```

***2nd query's answer:*** As per OP's 2nd query to ignore everything from `#` try following.

```
diff <(sed 's/#.*//' file1) <(sed 's/#.*//' file2)
```

Comment: Thanks! It was working fine. Please can you answer my second query? which is ignoring everything after a '#' character in the line should be ignored by diff

Comment: @AkashTadwai, sure please check my 2nd solution and let me know if that helps you?